# why do I have different versions of gradle and gradle wrapper?

Tags: java, gradle

Why do I have different versions of gradle and gradle wrapper?

`gradle --version` returns `Gradle 7.4.2` while  `./gradlew --version` returns `Gradle 7.2`

I use IntelliJ IDEA as IDE for my java project and my preferences are at default:[image]

In my project in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` there is a line

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip

But why it does not match with my installed version?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

From [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_version_install):

> In the **Use Gradle from** list select one of the following options:
>
> **'gradle-wrapper.properties'** file: this is a recommended default option that uses Gradle wrapper.
>
> In this case you delegate the update of Gradle versions to Gradle and get an automatic Gradle download for the build. This option also lets you build with a precise Gradle version. The Gradle version is saved in the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file in the **gradle** directory of your project and helps you eliminate any Gradle version problems.
>
> **Specified location**: select this option if you want to manually download and use a specific Gradle version. Specify the location of your Gradle installation and JVM under which IntelliJ IDEA will run Gradle when you import the specified Gradle project and when you execute its tasks.